# Difference between passing array and array pointer into function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, parameter-passing, space-efficiency

What is the difference between these two functions in C?

```c
void f1(double a[]) {
   //...
}

void f2(double *a) {
   //...
}
```

If I were to call the functions on a substantially long array, would these two functions behave differently?  Would one use more stack space than the other?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

First, some [standardese](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> **6.7.5.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)**
> ...
> 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type*’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
> *type*’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the
> array type derivation. If the keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the
> array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding
> actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many
> elements as specified by the size expression.

So, in short, any function parameter declared as `T a[]` or `T a[N]` is treated *as though* it were declared `T *a`.

So, why are array parameters treated as though they were declared as pointers?  Here's why:

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> ...
> 3 Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator or the unary `&` operator, or is a
> string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is
> converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points to the initial element of
> the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the
> behavior is undefined.

Given the following code:

```
int main(void)
{
  int arr[10];
  foo(arr);
  ...
}
```

In the call to `foo`, the array expression `arr` isn't an operand of either `sizeof` or `&`, so its type is implicitly converted from "10-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`" according to 6.2.3.1/3. Thus, `foo` will receive a pointer value, rather than an array value.

Because of 6.7.5.3/7, you can write `foo` as

```
void foo(int a[]) // or int a[10]
{
  ...
}
```

but it will be interpreted as

```
void foo(int *a)
{
  ...
}
```

Thus, the two forms are identical.

The last sentence in 6.7.5.3/7 was introduced with C99, and basically means that if you have a parameter declaration like

```
void foo(int a[static 10])
{
  ...
}
```

the actual parameter corresponding to `a` must be an array with *at least* 10 elements.

Comment: There is a difference when using (at least some older) MSVC C++ compilers, due to the compiler incorrectly mangling the function name differently in the two cases (while recognizing that they are the same otherwise), resulting in link problems. See "Won't fix" bug report here http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/326874/inconsistent-name-mangling-for-functions-accepting-array-and-pointer-parameters

Answer (score 36):

The difference is purely syntaxic. In C, when the array notation is used for a function parameter, it is automatically transformed into a pointer declaration.

Comment: @Kaushik: Though they are the same in this case, keep in mind that they are not the same [in the general case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096448/do-these-statements-about-pointers-have-the-same-effect)

Comment: @BlueRaja: yes, it is one of the pitfalls of C. The declaration of function parameters is _very similar_ to the declaration of local variables, but there are a few subtle differences (such as this array-to-pointer automatic transform) which are prone to bite the unwary programmer.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no difference between them. To test I wrote this C code in Dev C++(mingw) compiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int* array) {
     int a =5;
}

void main() {  
     int array[]={2,4};
     function(array);
     getch();
}
```

When I disassemble **main** function in .exe of both calling versions of binary file in IDA I get exactly the same assembly code like below:

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
sub     esp, 18h
and     esp, 0FFFFFFF0h
mov     eax, 0
add     eax, 0Fh
add     eax, 0Fh
shr     eax, 4
shl     eax, 4
mov     [ebp+var_C], eax
mov     eax, [ebp+var_C]
call    sub_401730
call    sub_4013D0
mov     [ebp+var_8], 2
mov     [ebp+var_4], 4
lea     eax, [ebp+var_8]
mov     [esp+18h+var_18], eax
call    sub_401290
call    _getch
leave
retn
```

So there is no difference between the two versions of this call, at least the compiler threats them equally.

Comment: Sorry, but this only proves that some version of gcc generates the same assembly on x86 for both. Correct answer, wrong explanation.