# Is there any difference between these two declarations?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between passing array and array pointer into function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573310/difference-between-passing-array-and-array-pointer-into-function-in-c)

I have been wondering this for a while, is there any difference between these two?

```
void f1(char *c);
void f2(char c[]);
```

A common example is this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

Are there any reasons to prefer one to the other, apart from artistic ones?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573310/difference-between-passing-array-and-array-pointer-into-function-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference.

From the horse mouth:

> (C99, 6.7.5.3p7) "A declaration of a parameter as "array of type" shall be adjusted to "qualified pointer to type", where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation."

On the reasons to prefer one form over the other, it depends on the people. Here is what H&S says (on switching to `T *array` from `T arr[]`):

> (H&S, 5.4.3 Array Bounds) "That would more accurately reflect the implementation but less clearly indicate the intent."

Comment: Who are H&S? Google isn't very helpful with such a short query.

Comment: Harbison & Steele http://careferencemanual.com

Comment: [Harbison & Steele](http://careferencemanual.com/).

Comment: Thanks. Would you recommend it to me? (I'm intermediate at C right now).

Comment: Totally, it is one the best book around for C. Note that it's a reference book.

Answer (score 2):

No. In a function declaration/definition, the use of an array as an argument is syntactic sugar only. It's still passed as a pointer, and `sizeof(theArgument)` will still give you `sizeof(TheType *)` rather than `sizeof(TheType) * sizeof(numElements)`.

Answer (score 1):

Well first one indicates that this is a pointer and the second that this is an array. While there is no effective difference, when you read the code you generally expect a single element in the first case an a sequence of more then one element in the second case. This might be helpful sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. Every n-dimensional array in both C and C++ can be interpreted as both n-dimensional array and pointer to (n-1)-dimensional array (as the pointer's `[]` semantic is same as array's one).