# difference of array related function arguments in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have defined an array:

```
float array[3][4][5];
```

then, what is the difference when

```
array, array[0], array[0][0], &array[0][0][0]
```

used as function argument?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between passing array and array pointer into function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573310/difference-between-passing-array-and-array-pointer-into-function-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important thing to learn is that, in C, arrays aren't passed as parameters in their entirety. Instead, the pointer to the first element of the array is passed.

So, given the definition `float array[3][4][5];`...

`array` (as a parameter) will be of type `float (*)[4][5]`, a pointer to a two-dimensional array of floats (explanation: we can't pass the array, we pass the pointer to its first element, which is a 4x5 array, hence `float (*)[4][5]`).

`array[0]` (as a parameter) will be of type `float (*)[5]`, a pointer to a one-dimensional array of floats (explanation: `array[0]` is a 4x5 array, we can't pass the array, we pass the pointer to the first element of it, the first element being an array of 5 elements, hence `float (*)[5]`).

`array[0][0]` (as a parameter) will be of type `float *`, a pointer to a float (explanation: `array[0][0]` is an array of 5 elements, we can't pass the array, we pass the pointer to the first element of it, the first element being a float, hence `float *`).

`&array[0][0][0]` (as a parameter) will be of type `float *`, a pointer to a float (explanation: `array[0][0][0]` is a `float`, we pass a pointer to it, hence `float *`).

Perhaps, a more elaborate example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x[3][5] =
{
  {  1,  2,  3,  4,  5 },
  {  6,  7,  8,  9, 10 },
  { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 }
};

int (*pArr35)[3][5] = &x;
// &x is a pointer to an array of 3 arrays of 5 ints.

int (*pArr5a)[5] = x;
// x decays from an array of arrays of 5 ints to
// a pointer to an array of 5 ints,
// x is a pointer to an array of 5 ints.

int (*pArr5b)[5] = &x[0];
// &x[0] is a pointer to 0th element of x,
// x[0] is an array of 5 ints,
// &x[0] is a pointer to an array of 5 ints.

int *pInta = x[0];
// x[0] is 0th element of x,
// x[0] is an array of 5 ints,
// x[0] decays from an array of 5 ints to
// a pointer to an int.

int *pIntb = *x;
// x decays from an array of arrays of 5 ints to
// a pointer to an array of 5 ints,
// x is a pointer to an array of 5 ints,
// *x is an array of 5 ints,
// *x decays from an array of 5 ints to
// a pointer to an int.

int *pIntc = &x[0][0];
// x[0][0] is 0th element of x[0],
// where x[0] is an array of 5 ints,
// x[0][0] is an int,
// &x[0][0] is a pointer to an int.

int main(void)
{
  printf("&x=%p x=%p &x[0]=%p x[0]=%p *x=%p &x[0][0]=%p\n",
         pArr35, pArr5a, pArr5b, pInta, pIntb, pIntc);

  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/NDvca)):

```
&x=0x804a040 x=0x804a040 &x[0]=0x804a040 x[0]=0x804a040 *x=0x804a040 &x[0][0]=0x804a040
```

Answer (score 1):

All are points to same location.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {

    float array[3][4][5];
    printf("\n Address : %p, \n%p, \n%p, \n%p\n",array, array[0], array[0][0], &array[0][0][0]);
printf("\n Address : %p, \n%p, \n%p, \n%p\n",array+1, array[0]+1, array[0][0]+1, &array[0][0][0] + 1);

    return 0;
    }
```

gave me

```
    Address : 0x7fff51a2cac0, 
0x7fff51a2cac0, 
0x7fff51a2cac0, 
0x7fff51a2cac0

 Address : 0x7fff51a2cb10, 
0x7fff51a2cad4, 
0x7fff51a2cac4, 
0x7fff51a2cac4
```

The main difference comes when we increment the addresses.

```
array + 1       gives array[1][0][0]
array[0] + 1    gives array[0][1][0] 

then both array[0][0]+1 and &array[0][0][0] + 1 will points to array[0][0][1].
```

Comment: thank you very much, in fact, i also think they are the same addresses or pointers that point to the same place, but there must be some difference, because when i misuse them, compilation errors or something else come up

Comment: That answer doesn't tell all the differences.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `float[3][4][5]`, `float[4][5]`, `float[5]`, or `float*` in those cases, but all of them degenerate to `float*` when required.

See [Difference between passing array and array pointer into function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573310/difference-between-passing-array-and-array-pointer-into-function-in-c)

Comment: Inside the function the parameters are of types: `float (*)[4][5]`, `float (*)[5]`, `float *` and `float *`.

Answer (score 0):

There are no difference if you want to pass it into a function, because you can pass only pointer to array. But in function you can take as arguments sizes of array and calculate proper members by yourself.

Comment: The parameter types are definitely different, even though their values (they are all pointers) are equal.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of accessibility,

```
array = gives 3 dimensional array
array[0] = gives 2 dimensional array which is in array's 0th index
array[0][0] = gives 1 dimensional array which is in array's (0,0)th index
&array[0][0][0] = gives float *
```

if you says `array[0][0][0]`, it gives just a `float` variable which is in first place

Comment: You should probably elaborate this further since arrays aren't passed in their entirety, instead pointers to their element 0 are passed.

Answer (score 0):

As said, there is no difference.

For example, if you have an array

```
float x[10][10];
```

You can reference 3-d item int the first "row", using two different ways:

```
x[1][3]
```

or

*(*(x+1) + 3)

Comment: The parameter types are definitely different, even though their values (they are all pointers) are equal.

Comment: Yep, can agree with you. It's 'C' feature in this case to *silently* convert them.