# how the compiler interprets &a[0]+1 and &a+1 calculation

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
    int * ptr;
    ptr =(int *) &a;
    printf("\n&a:%u,&a[0]:%u,ptr:%u\n",&a,&a[0],ptr);
    ptr = (int*)(&a+1);
    printf("\n&a:%u,&a[0]:%u,ptr:%u\n",&a,&a[0],ptr);
    ptr = (int*)(&a);
    ptr = (int*)(&a[0]+4);
    printf("\n&a:%u,&a[0]:%u,ptr:%u,*ptr:%d\n",&a,&a[0],ptr,*ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

> o/p:

```
&a:3213284540,&a[0]:3213284540,ptr:3213284540

&a:3213284540,&a[0]:3213284540,ptr:3213284560

&a:3213284540,&a[0]:3213284540,ptr:3213284556,*ptr:4
```

In the above code `&a` and `&a[0]` gives the same address `3213284540`. But the two cases when added with `1` gives different address.

```
&a[0]+1 => 3213284540 + 4     = 3213284544   [The value stored in this address is '1']
&a+1    => 3213284540 + (5*4) = 3213284560   [Goes Out of bounds of the array] 

&a+1 is equivalent to sizeof(array)+1.
```

> But how the compiler interprets this `&a[0]+1` and `&a+1` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference of array related function arguments in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385267/difference-of-array-related-function-arguments-in-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But how the compiler interprets this &a[0]+1 and &a+1

It's pointer arithmetic, so it's always important to know the pointed types and one basic thing: adding `1` to a pointer makes it point to some "next" element.

- In your example `&a[0]` is of type `int *` so adding 1 **moves the
  pointer to the next int**. So the address should increase by 4/8
  bytes or so, depending on `sizeof(int)`
- However, `&a` is of type `int (*)[5]`. So adding 1 to it **moves the
  pointer to the next array**. In effect, the address should increase
  by `sizeof(a)`.

---

Side note: use `%p` when printing pointer values.

Comment: Was hoping to harp on someone for not knowing that taking the address of an array results in *a pointer to an array of <whatever>*... but I was dissapointed :D. +1