# Traverse through layers of array using pointer to layer of array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
                         |--------|     
//                     / |4  4  4 |     
//                   |--------| 4 | 
//                 / |3  3  3 | 4 | 
//               |---------|3 |   |
//             / | 2  2  2 |3 | /
//            |---------|2 |__|
//            | 1  1  1 |2 | /
//            | 1  1  1 |__| 
//            | 1  1  1 | /
//            |_________|
double arr[4][3][3] = {{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},{3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},{4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4}};
```

I consider that this array consists of *4 layers*.

I want to create *pointer to layer of array* and traverse through layers of that array using pointer.

**I try :**

```
double (*pp1)[sizeof(arr[0]) / sizeof(ar[0][0][0])]; 
pp1 = arr[0];
```

and get error from intelIsense:
value of type (double (*)(3) can`t be assigned to double(*)(9)

Comment: At a quick guess, you want `double (*pp1)[sizeof(arr[0]) / sizeof(ar[0][0])];`

Comment: i need sizeof(arr[0]) / sizeof(ar[0][0][0] which is 9 (number of elements in layer). I changed int on double, it was typo

Comment: +1 for awesome 3D graphics but give up this madness and embrace proper data structures.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph )) thnx, but I got task which I want to do by means of pointer to layer of array, actually I want to figure out how pointers on array works

Comment: Try this
double (*pp1)[sizeof(arr[0]) / sizeof(arr[0][0])] = arr[0];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to figure out this issue i got some results.

I find out that the following statements raises no errors from compiler

```
double arr[4][4][9];
double (*pp3)[9];
pp3 = arr[0];
```

So, is it right to deduce from code above that pointer can be assigned to array only in case if number of elements to which it points is equall to the smallest dimension of array?

update:
I think that pointer can be created on the smallest layer of array only.

Can somebody explain this?

Comment: @Alexey Frunze- yes, thanks a lot for the good source of information. Now I understand how to use pointers on arrays, which is quite clearly explained in answer you gave me.

Answer (score 1):

So if you do:

```
int i;
double arr[4][3][3] = {{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
                       {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},{4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4}};

double (*pp3)[3][3];    
pp3 = arr;    
for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)    
{   printf("pp3 + %d is %f \n", i, ***(pp3 + i));
}
```

Then you get the desired behavior. The problem with your code is that, just as the compiler is telling you, you are trying to assign a pointer to an array of 9 double (`double (*pp1)[sizeof(arr[0] / sizeof(arr[0][0][0])]` evaluates to `double (*pp1)[9]` ), but you need a pointer to an array of 3 of array of 3, which is what you declared with `double arr[4][3][3]`. From my tests, gcc will accept the `double (*pp1)[9]` with a compiler warning, which is what I tried to get at in my comment below. Hope that clears things up.

If you want to keep this general, then what you really want is `double (*pp3)[sizeof(arr[0]) / sizeof(arr[0][0])][sizeof(arr[0][0]) / sizeof(arr[0][0][0])]`, which is a bloody nightmare.

EDIT: Forgot a dereference... Should've copy/pasted haha. Also added explanation about the question's code behavior. Fixed as per comments.

Comment: On second thought, it's proper to do `(*pp3)[3][3]`, which is a pointer to an array of 3 of array of 3, which is what you have. The original (using `(*pp3)[9]`) works, but since we don't really have an array of 9, I believe that's where the error was coming from...

Comment: If you want to keep this general, then what you really want is `double (*pp3)[sizeof(arr[0]) / sizeof(arr[0][0])][sizeof(arr[0][0]) / sizeof(arr[0][0][0])]`, which is a bloody nightmare. Gotta agree with using proper data structures... but this will do what you asked, properly. I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: double (*pp3)[3][3];    
pp3 = arr[0];  wan`t compile.
to compile code you have to declare pointer as:
double (*pp3)[3] - because arr[0] is pointer to the first element of arr, which has dimensions [3][3], as you declaring pointer on this element, it is also points to first element of [3][3] array, which is (*pp3)[3]. Alexey Frunze gave reference on very detailed explanation of usage of pointers to arrays, here it is http://stackoverflow.com/a/12385772/968261

Comment: Sorry, that was an artifact from a prior revision. It should be `(*pp3)[3][3]; pp3 = arr;` . I should really copy/paste instead of retyping... I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply get the direction of the first element of a given layer?

```
double *pp1 = &ar[0][0][0];
double *pp2 = &ar[1][0][0];
/* and so on */
```

Comment: How this solution  will help me to figure out how pointers to layer of array work?