# how does p become a 2-D array after the call to malloc?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

The following snippet declares a 2-D array of *4 X 10* using `malloc` function

```
/* Declare a pointer to an array that has 10
ints in each row. */
int (*p)[10];
register int i, j;
/* allocate memory to hold a 4 x 10 array */
p = malloc(40*sizeof(int));
```

But I do not understand how does `p` become a 2-D array. Initially p is declared to be an array of pointers that point to int. What happens after the call to malloc ? I am unable understand this.

Comment: nice idea of allocating 2D array in contiguous memory location without using for loop :)

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12385772/968261) useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, pointers and arrays are not the same, despite looking very similar. Here `p` is of type "pointer to array of 10 ints". You're using it as a "pointer to array of 4 arrays of 10 ints", which is a single block of memory (the only pointer is the outermost pointer). It's basically a dynamically allocated `int[4][10]`.

The trick to reading these definitions is to realize that they're written the same way you use the item. If you have:

```
*x[10];
```

The array subscript is applied first, *then* the pointer dereference. So it's an array of pointers if you define `int *x[10]`. If you use parenthesis to override normal precedence, you can get the pointer dereference to happen first, so you have a pointer to an array.

Confusing? It gets worse. In function arguments, the *outermost array* of a function parameter is converted into a pointer.

```
int *p[10]; // array of 10 pointer to int
int (*p)[10]; // pointer to array of 10 ints
void foo(int *p[10] /* pointer to pointer to int */);
void foo(int (*p)[10] /* pointer to array of 10 ints */);
```

Further, arrays are converted to pointers when you use them.

```
int x[10]; // array of 10 int
sizeof(x); // 10 * sizeof(int)
int *y = x; // implicitly converts to a pointer to &x[0]!
sizeof(y); // sizeof(int *)
```

This means that you can allocate memory for an array of arrays, then let that implicitly convert to a pointer to an array, which you in turn use as if it were an array of arrays!

Anyway, this is all very confusing so please do not ever use this in production code - at least, not without a clarifying typedef:

```
typedef int vector[3];
vector *array_of_vectors; // actually a pointer to a vector, 
                          // but you can use it as an aray to a vector if enough
                          // memory is allocated
```

Comment: Here: `int x[10]; // pointer to 10 int` x is an array of 10 ints.

Comment: +1, but I don't find it confusing: there are just three rules to remember. (1) arrays are not pointers unless (2) they are the outermost `[]` specification of a function parameter, or (3) used as values in expressions.

Answer (score 3):

The memory, worth 40 ints, is reserved to the pointer p. p points at his memory block. It so happens that p chooses to organize this memory as 10 equal parts, each of which happen to hold 4 ints' worth.

That's if this code is actually correct. My C is very rusty at this point.

Comment: It helps to think of `p[x][y]` as just shorthand for `((int*)p)[10*x+y]`, the constant 10 coming from the declaration of `p`.

Comment: The other way around: `p` points at 4 entities, each of which is another 10 entities, each of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

First, some background information:

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" is converted ("decays") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and its value is the address of the first element in the array.  For example, given the array

```
int a[10];
```

anytime the expression `a` appears in the code, its type will be converted from "10-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`", or `int *`, *except* for cases like `sizeof a`, `_Alignof a`, and `&a`.  If we have a 2D array of T, such as

```
int a[10][10];
```

the expression `a` will be converted from type "10-element array of 10-element array of `int`" to "pointer to 10-element array of `int`", or **`int (*)[10]`** (look familiar? that's the type of your pointer `p`).

If we want to dynamically allocate an N-element array of type `T`, we write something like

```
T *p = malloc(N * sizeof *p);
```

`sizeof *p` is equivalent to `sizeof (T)`.  In this particular case, type `T` is "10-element array of `int`", or `int [10]`.  We want to allocate 4 such arrays, so we can write

```
int (*p)[10];
p = malloc(4 * sizeof *p);
```

This allocates space for 4 10-element arrays of `int`, and assigns the result to `p`. (`sizeof *p == sizeof (int [10])`).

So how does this become a 2D array?

Remember that the expression `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)`; we find the address of the `i`'th *element* of type `T` following `a` and dereference the result.  In this case `p[i]` gives us the address of the `i`th *10-element array of `int`* following `p`.  Since we dereference the pointer as part of the subscript operation, the *type* of the expression `p[i]` is "10-element array of `int`".  Thus we can subscript this expression again and get `p[i][j]`.