# c++ passing arrays through functions

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I can't figure out why this wont run. I am supposed to store`hours * payrate` in the wages array and then `showResults` take this info and `cout` it. The error i get when i run it is

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl showResults(int * const,int,double * const,double * const,double * const)" (?showResults@@YAXQAHHQAN11@Z) referenced in function
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl getEmployeeData(int * const,int,double * const,double * const,double * const)" (?getEmployeeData@@YAXQAHHQAN11@Z) referenced in function `_main`
```

Code below:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void getEmployeeData(int[], int, double[], double[], double[]);
void showResults(int[], int, double[], double[], double[]);


int main()
{
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 7;
int empId[ARRAY_SIZE] = {565, 845, 452, 130, 789, 758, 877};

double hoursWorked[ARRAY_SIZE]; // Holds hours worked
double payrate[ARRAY_SIZE]; // Holds pay rate
double wages[ARRAY_SIZE]; // Holds wages

getEmployeeData(empId, ARRAY_SIZE, payrate, hoursWorked, wages);

showResults(empId, ARRAY_SIZE, payrate, hoursWorked, wages);

system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void getEmployeedata(int nums[],int size,double pay[],double hours[],
double wages[])
{

//Hours worked and Pay rate
for(int index = 0; index < size; index++)
{
    cout << "Enter number of hours worked by employee number "
         << nums[index] << ": ";
    cin >> hours[index]; 
    cout << "\nEnter hourly pay rate ";
    cin >> pay[index];
    wages[index] = hours[index] * pay[index]; 
}
}

void showResults(int nums[], int size, double pay, double hours, double wages[])
{
for(int index = 0; index < size; index++)
{
    cout << "Employee Number Gross Wage " << endl
         << nums[index] << " " << wages[index];

}

}
```

Comment: The C++ Standard Library provides a rich set of [container types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). These can easily be passed in and out of functions. You should use these instead of old-school arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass arrays to functions, also try writing functions as

```
void getEmployeeData(int*, int, double*, double*, double*);
void showResults(int*, int, double*, double*, double*);
```

because when you pass array, you are passing pointer to the 0th index of that array.
Also, as told, there is a typo in your code, replace `getEmployeedata` with `getEmployeeData`

Here is the corrected code :

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void getEmployeeData(int*, int, double*, double*, double*);
void showResults(int*, int, double*, double*, double*);


int main()
{
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 7;
int empId[7] = {565, 845, 452, 130, 789, 758, 877};

double hoursWorked[ARRAY_SIZE]; // Holds hours worked
double payrate[ARRAY_SIZE]; // Holds pay rate
double wages[ARRAY_SIZE]; // Holds wages

getEmployeeData(empId, ARRAY_SIZE, payrate, hoursWorked, wages);

showResults(empId, ARRAY_SIZE, payrate, hoursWorked, wages);

system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void getEmployeeData(int nums[],int size,double pay[],double hours[],double wages[])
{

//Hours worked and Pay rate
for(int index = 0; index < size; index++)
{
    cout << "Enter number of hours worked by employee number "
         << nums[index] << ": ";
    cin >> hours[index];
    cout << "\nEnter hourly pay rate ";
    cin >> pay[index];
    wages[index] = hours[index] * pay[index];
}
}

void showResults(int *nums, int size, double *pay, double *hours, double *wages)
{
for(int index = 0; index < size; index++)
{
    cout << "Employee Number Gross Wage " << endl
         << nums[index] << " " << wages[index];

}

}
```

Comment: What's the difference between a pointer and the way that i had it? In my book the only way i see it is like [].

Comment: There is no difference apart from syntax, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573310/difference-between-passing-array-and-array-pointer-into-function-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

The declaration and definition of `showResults` disagree about argument types. In particular, the `pay` and `hours` arguments are `double[]` in the declaration but only `double` in the definition.

```
void showResults(int[], int, double[], double[], double[]) // Declaration
//                                 ↕↕        ↕↕
void showResults(int[], int, double  , double  , double[]) // Definition
```

It appears that the declaration is correct and the definition is not, since you are passing arrays to them.

Your declaration and definitions of `getEmployeeData` disagree about the name.

```
void getEmployeeData(int[], int, double[], double[], double[]) // Declaration
/               ↕
void getEmployeedata(int[], int, double[], double[], double[]) // Definition
```

You probably want `getEmployeeData` to be consistent with the rest of your naming.

Comment: Thanks! i must've been overlooking that

Comment: Better yet, `double *`.  Having array-types parameters is a convenient lie, they get turned into pointers.  (OTOH reference to array is a distinct type)

Comment: @Ben Voigt So instead of double[], it should be double*? Why is that?

Comment: @user1807815: Because the language says the actual parameter type is `double*`, even if you write `double[]`.  (Implication: If you use `sizeof` inside the function, you get the size of a pointer)

Answer (score 1):

Your function names have typo:

```
getEmployeeData(empId, ARRAY_SIZE, payrate, hoursWorked, wages);
```

However, in definition youhave:

```
getEmployeedata(...);
```

also mismatch here:

```
 void showResults(int nums[], int size, double pay, double hours, double wages[])
                                            //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know exactly how many elements each array has, you can try making `ARRAY_SIZE` a global constant (so it's in the same scope as your function prototypes), allowing you to do something like this:

```
void getEmployeeData(int (&)[ARRAY_SIZE], int, double (&)[ARRAY_SIZE], double (&)[ARRAY_SIZE], double (&)[ARRAY_SIZE]);
void showResults(int (&)[ARRAY_SIZE], int, double (&)[ARRAY_SIZE], double (&)[ARRAY_SIZE], double (&)[ARRAY_SIZE]);

void getEmployeeData(int (&nums)[ARRAY_SIZE], int size, double (&pay)[ARRAY_SIZE], double (&hours)[ARRAY_SIZE], double (&wages)[ARRAY_SIZE]) {
// Function body
}
void showResults(int (&nums)[ARRAY_SIZE], int size, double (&pay)[ARRAY_SIZE], double (&hours)[ARRAY_SIZE], double (&wages)[ARRAY_SIZE]) {
// Function body
}
```

Now, this looks awkward, but what it does is tell the compiler that the function takes references to arrays with **exactly** `ARRAY_SIZE` elements.  (Specifically, `[]` has higher precedence than `&`, so you need the parentheses to tell the compiler that the argument is a reference to an array instead of an array of references.)  It also allows you to use the ol' C `sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0])` to determine the arrays' size; unlike letting the array decay into a pointer (in which case `sizeof` would give you useless information because it sees `nums` as an `int*` instead of an `int[ARRAY_SIZE]`), passing it by reference preserves this information.

---

Alternatively, if you're free to rewrite the code and your compiler supports C++11, you can use `std::array` instead of C-style arrays.

```
#include <array>
using namespace std;

void getEmployeeData(array<int, ARRAY_SIZE>, int, array<double, ARRAY_SIZE>, array<double, ARRAY_SIZE>, array<double, ARRAY_SIZE>);
void showResults(array<int, ARRAY_SIZE>, int, array<double, ARRAY_SIZE>, array<double, ARRAY_SIZE>, array<double, ARRAY_SIZE>);


array<int, ARRAY_SIZE> empId = {565, 845, 452, 130, 789, 758, 877};

array<double, ARRAY_SIZE> hoursWorked; // Holds hours worked
array<double, ARRAY_SIZE> payrate; // Holds pay rate
array<double, ARRAY_SIZE> wages; // Holds wages
```

As a container, `std::array` can be used with the same syntax as a C-style array (i.e. `operator[]`), so you shouldn't need to rewrite any of the code that actually uses the arrays.  It also lets `getEmployeeData()` and `showResults()` check the arrays' size directly, with something like `nums.size()`.

Also note that if you use either of these, you don't actually need to pass `int size`, since you can use `sizeof` or `std::array.size()`.  This does have the downside of polluting the global namespace a bit, though, but I personally consider it to be a fair tradeoff for the security of guaranteeing that your code will only compile if the functions are given properly sized arrays.

[Note that if you need to be able to pass differently sized arrays at different times, neither of these methods will be of use to you.]

I apologise for any typoes I may have missed.