# Custom Function with array input: Error:|Cannot cast float to float*| without any cast

Tags: c, arrays, casting, average

I wanted to make a program which obtains temperature of each day of 2 months
and prints the average for each day

The error code is at the line where the day_avg() is called.
(Cannot Cast float to float*)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void day_avg(float month[],float month2[]);

int main()
{
    float jul[31]={ 31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31 };
    float aug[31]={ 31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31 };
    day_avg(jul[31],aug[31]);
}
void day_avg(float month[],float month2[]){
    int i;
    float avg[31]={0};
    for(i=0;i<31;i++)
        avg[i]=(month[i]+month2[i])/2.0;
    for(i=0;i<31;i++)
        printf("\nAverage of temperature of 2 months for day %d :%.1f",i+1,avg[i]);
}
```

Comment: I could not write down the actual 31 values because of auto-fit issues with this site.

Comment: change to `day_avg(jul,aug);`

Comment: *"I could not write down the actual 31 values because of auto-fit issues with this site."* Sure you can. A horizontal scrollbar will appear if necessary. (There's no particular need to, the question is clear enough without, but the site isn't preventing you from doing it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `day_avg(jul[31],aug[31])` should be `day_avg(jul, aug)`

`jul` and `aug` are references to arrays, they know how big they are so specifying it in function calls like that is wrong and doesn't do what you might think. What actually happens is that you send the value from array index 31 of `jul` and `aug` instead of the whole array.

Second problem is that array index 31 is out of bounds for your arrays, valid indexes are `0-30` in an array of size 31.

You want to send in the whole array, temperature data for all days, hence `day_avg(jul, aug)`

Comment: @niCk: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573310/difference-between-passing-array-and-array-pointer-into-function-in-c

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your function wrong

```
day_avg(jul[31],aug[31]);
```

`day_avg` expects arguments of type `float *`.
As array names are  decays to pointer when passed to functions as arguments (not always), you can call it as

```
 day_avg(jul, aug);
```

**EDIT:** As per the OP's comment: *I defined the input as `month[]` not `month*` , i thought the array itself was the input*

Compiler parsed

```
void day_avg(float month[], float month2[]);
```

as

```
void day_avg(float *month, float *month2);
```

You can't pass an entire array to a function but address to the first element.

---

**SIDE NOTE:**
Also if `day_avg` made to accept argument of type `float` then you can't pass `jul[31],aug[31]` as array indexing statrts from `0` in C.

Answer (score 1):

Your `void day_avg(float month[],float month2[])` function is expecting pointer and you are passing value. You should pass like this `day_avg(jul,aug);`

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

Missing ; at the end

> ```
> float jul[31]={ 31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31 };
> float aug[31]={ 31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31 };
> ```

Second function should be like:

> day_avg(jul,aug);