# Why it is not an error to increment array "a" in the below function?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
void printd(char []);
int main(void){
       char a[100];
       a[0]='a';a[1]='b';a[2]='c';a[4]='d';
       printd(a);
       return 0;
}
void printd(char a[]){
        a++;
        printf("%c",*a);
        a++;
        printf("%c",*a);
}
```

Explanation: I was expecting that it would result in lvalue error.
But it is working with out any error and giving bc as output. Why is this incrementing array "a" is not an error?

Comment: [Because you're not incrementing an array.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150326025620/http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html)

Comment: If I had used a++(incrementing base address) in main function then I would have got error.

Comment: Yes, because the `a` in `main()` is an array and the `a` in `printd()` is a pointer.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6567742/694576 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/5573310/694576 (for references to the C Standard)

Comment: @alk Where can I find the C standard?

Comment: A C11 draft can be found here: port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If an array is passed to a function it *decays* to a pointer to the array's first element.

Due to this inside `printd()` the pointer `a` can be incremented and decremented, to point to different elements of the array `a` as defined in `main()`.

Please note that when declaring/defining a function's parameter list for any type `T` the expression `T[]` is equivaltent to `T*`.

In question's specific case

```
void printd(char a[]);
```

is the same as

```
void printd(char * a);
```

The code below shows equivalent behaviour as the OP's code, with `pa` behaving like `a` in side `printd()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   char a[100];
   a[0]='a';a[1]='b';a[2]='c';a[4]='d';

   {
     char * pa = a;

     pa++;
     printf("%c", *pa);
     pa++;
     printf("%c", *pa);
   }

   return 0;
`}
```

Answer (score 3):

In C language array declaration in function parameter list and array declaration outside of function parameter list mean completely different things, even though they look similar (or the same) on the surface.

When you use array declaration in function parameter list (as is the case with `void printd(char a[])` in your code), you are *not* declaring an array. The top-level `[]` syntax in function parameter list is just an alternative form of *pointer* declaration. This means that your `a` parameter is actually declared as `char *a`. It is not an array at all, it is an ordinary pointer. There's nothing unusual in being able to increment such `a`, and this is why you are not getting any "lvalue errors" from it.

Meanwhile, your `a` in `main` is a true array.

Comment: And _that_ is the actual correct explanation for the seemingly strange behaviour. You can't declare function parameters that are arrays. You can only use declarations that _look like_ array declarations.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this incrementing array "a" is not an error?

In C arrays are passed as a pointer to any function. Thats why you get no error.

The function calls in `main()` pass the *name* of the array, `a`, as an argument because the name of an array in an expression evaluates to a *pointer to the array*. In other words, the expression, `a`, is a pointer to (the first element of) the array, `a[]`. Its type is, therefore, `char *`, and a called function uses this pointer (passed as an argument) to indirectly access the elements of the array.

Now as you receive the *address* of the first element of `a`, `a++` means ahead the array's initial address by `1`. That's why the first `printf` prints  `b`, the second element of array `a`.

Comment: Still nitpicking: One does not pass the "name" of a variable, but the variable itself. So this "*pass the name of the array*" should read "*pass the array*".

Comment: Also not "*the name of an array ... evaluates*", but the array itself.

Comment: _name_ of the array is a metaphor which explained in the next line describing actually it means `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

a also works as a pointer. It is a pointer to the first element of the array. The a++ increments that pointer. That is, after a++ the a[0] or *a now gives you what a[1] gave you prior to the increment, that is 'b'.

Note that you do not increment the value of a[0] from 'a' to 'b'. Check that if you use different values in your array, like 'a, 'd', 'h', 'x'.

Comment: @Ticktick, If you want to increment the value of a[0], you should do something like (*a)++ - not too elegant in this case, but used nonetheless.

Comment: "*a++ increments the pointer to the array.*" This is not correct. `a` in `printd()` initially  is a pointer  to the 1st element of `a` as defined in `main()`. A pointer to an array is something different.

Answer (score 0):

An array is passed to a function as a pointer, which can be incremented.

So, in your example, it is not possible to increment `a` within the `main()` function, since `a` is an array and cannot be incremented.

However, not withstanding the syntax, the `a` within the `printd()` function is a pointer, so can be incremented.    Incrementing `a` inside `printd()` does not affect the array `a` inside main() - although they have the same names, they are different entities within different scopes.