# Calling by reference without explicitly declaring function parameters as pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm reading K&R and have a problem here. I don't know how this function is changing the value of the calling variable. Shouldn't this be call by value, not call by reference since to[] and from[] aren't explicity declared as pointers? The value of foo is changed to "Testing".

```
#include <stdio.h>

void copy(char to[], char from[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0') i++;
}

int main() {
    char foo[] = "";
    char bar[] = "Testing";
    copy(foo, bar);
    printf("%s\n", foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, why isn't this arr_alter function changing the value of test_arr? It seems that looping through each element in the array changes the value of the calling variable yet this does not.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void arr_alter(char arr[]) {
    arr = "Changed";
}

int main() {
    char test_arr[] = "Testing";
    arr_alter(test_arr);
    printf("%s\n", test_arr);
    return 0;
}
```

In short, why is function #1 treating the arguments as pointers while function #2 is not?

I'm a bit confused, all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryparmasgn.html) may help you understand. Your parameters are treated like pointers by the compiler.

Comment: Undefined behavior. Your first example tries to write outside the bounds of array foo, which is only one character long.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between passing array and array pointer into function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573310/difference-between-passing-array-and-array-pointer-into-function-in-c)

Comment: With `arr = "Changed"` you seem to be thinking of strings as things that can be passed around and assigned as easily as ints. It doesn't work that way in C -- strings are data structures. The syntax in  `char test_arr[] = "Testing";` looks like a simple assignment, but it really isn't. It is just syntactic sugar for initializing an array and can only be done once. You can't subsequently directly use  `=` to change that char array to hold a different string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays are passed as pointers, by value.

You can take

```
void copy(char to[], char from[])
```

as equivalent to

```
void copy(char * to, char * from)
```

The difference between the two cases is that the first case **dereferences** the pointer with the array element operator `[]`.
The second case does not do this, it overwrites the passed pointer. But the **pointer was passed by value**, so neither the array content nor the passed pointer of the caller change.

Comment: @Vlad found an error I overlooked, please change `char foo[] = ...` to `char foo[8];`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the first program has undefined behaviour.
Array `foo` is defined as having only one element (the terminating zero of the "empty" string literal)

```
char foo[] = "";
```

However you are going to copy string "Testing" in the array.

```
copy(foo, bar);
```

This results in overwritting the memory that does not belong to array `foo`.

Array `foo` should be enough large to be able to accomodate string "Testing".

For example

```
char foo[8];
```

According to the C Standard (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes))

> 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted
>   to ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any)
>   are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type
>   derivation....

On the other (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object** and is not an lvalue. If the array
>   object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Thus in this function declaration

```
void copy(char to[], char from[]);
```

parameters `to` and `from` are adjusted to pointers. So this function declaration is equivalent to the following function declaration

```
void copy(char *to, char *from);
```

and the both declare the same one function.

You may write in the program the both declarations. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void copy(char to[], char from[]);
void copy(char *to, char *from);

void copy(char to[], char from[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0') i++;
}
//...
```

but the definition of the function shall be only one.

And in this function call

```
copy(foo, bar);
```

according to the second quote from the Standard arrays `foo` and `bar` are converted to pointers to their first elements.

As for the function from the second program then function parameters are its local variables. A function deals with copies of its arguments. So any changes of a copy of an argument do not influence on the argument itself.

You can imagine the definition of function arr_alter and its call the following way

```
arr_alter(test_arr);

//...

void arr_alter( /*char arr[] */) {
    char *arr = test_arr;

    arr = "Changed";
}
```

After exiting the function its local variable `arr` will be destroyed.  Variable `test_arr` will not be changed and moreover arrays have no the assignment operator. You can not reassign an array such a way.

Answer (score 0):

char to[] and char from[] is the equivalent to assigning a char ptr to the first element of the array.

Say you had char s[10]= "hello";
print(s);

Is the same as

print(&s[0]);

The address of the first slot in the array.