# C function const size array parameter

Tags: c, function-prototypes

I've spot such a declaration in an external library:

```
StatusInfo SetName(const char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH]);
```

Which looks a little bit strange for me. I would declare this function as:

```
StatusInfo SetName(const char *name);
```

Is there any difference?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573310/difference-between-passing-array-and-array-pointer-into-function-in-c

Comment: Why it looks strange to you ? They are pretty clear declarations.