# function not returning anything but its data member (char array) can be accessed in main function. How is this possible?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(char a[],char b[])
{
    a[0]='t';
    a[1]='e';
    a[2]='s';
    a[3]='t';
    a[4]='_';
    a[5]='a';
    a[6]=NULL;

    b[0]='t';
    b[1]='e';
    b[2]='s';
    b[3]='t';
    b[4]='_';
    b[5]='b';
    b[6]=NULL;

}

int main()
{
    char a[10],b[10];
    foo(a,b);
    printf("%s \n",a);    //outputs "test_a"
    printf("%s \n",b);    //outputs "test_b"
}
```

How does `a[]` and `b[]` char arrays in `main()` get its value, when `foo()` is neither using pointers nor returning any value when it is called through `main()`?

Correct me if I am wrong in saying "`foo()` is not using pointers".

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5573310/274261

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function `foo()` **is actually using** pointers, somehow. When arrays are passed to functions, it decays to the pointer to the first element of the array.

As it happens,

```
void foo(char a[],char b[])
```

and

```
void foo(char *a,char *b)
```

are perfectly interchangeable.

In your case, when called with parameters like `foo(a,b);`, from the function you can change the content of the memory area pointed by `a` and `b`. You don't need to return anything.