# Are the following two functions equivalent? If not, why not?

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, char

```
void s1(char dest[], char src[])
{
    int i=0;
    while(dest[i++]=src[i++]);
}

void s2(char * dest, char *src)
{
    while(*dest++=*src++);
}
```

Also, note that I took this problem from a book, and don't know if the code is correct or not(I think there should be two '=' in the while loop)

Comment: It's just a few lines of code; couldn't you at least *try* and format it properly before posting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between passing array and array pointer into function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573310/difference-between-passing-array-and-array-pointer-into-function-in-c)

Comment: @Akos Nagy, Re "*I think there should be two '=' in the while loop*", No, then it won't copy anything. The functions are (attempts to) reimplement `strcpy`.

Comment: @minigeek, Re "*Its an infinite loop basically since it is =*", No, it stops after copying a NUL. The functions are (attempts to) reimplement `strcpy`.

Comment: did it not tell you in the book?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second code performs a string copy. It is equivalent to `strcpy()`.

The first code has undefined behaviour because it updates `i` twice in one statement without an intervening sequence point.

So the answer is that they are not the same.

The first code could be corrected. For example like this:

```
void s1(char dest[], char src[])
{
    int i=0;
    while(dest[i]=src[i]) i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters these function declarations

```
void sh1(char dest[], char src[]);
```

and

```
void s2(char * dest, char *src);
```

are equivalent because function parameters declared like arrays are adjusted to pointers to objects with types that corresponds to the array element types.

You even can include in one compilation unit the both declarations of a function with the same name and they will declare the same one function (though the function definition must be one provided that the function is not an inline function).

So the question is about whether the expressions used in the loops that is

```
while(dest[i++]=src[i++]);
```

and

```
while(*dest++=*src++);
```

yield the same result.

The first loop has undefined behavior. You should rewrite it like

```
while(dest[i] = src[i]) i++;
```

As for example `dest++` increases the pointer it can be rewritten like `dest = dest + 1`. Thus applying the operator ++ several times to the pointer you will get that it is equivalent to the expression `dest = ( dest + 1 ) + 1 + ... +1;` Ot it can be written like `dest = dest + i;` where `i` is the sum of `1 + 1 ...+ 1`

So for each iteration of the loops these expressions

`*dest++` and `dest[i], i++`

yield the same result.

Comment: unfortunately `dest[i++]=src[i++]` is UB as Klas pointed out.

Comment: @bolov Oh I even did not see that the index is increased two times.:)