# What does int values[] mean?

Tags: c

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
```

I just started learning c language.I am not sure what type of data `int values[]` means,can you help me?thx.

Comment: Lesson $%#: C is not the same as C++. Do not tag with both.

Comment: @StoryTeller perhaps this would have been better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573310/difference-between-passing-array-and-array-pointer-into-function-in-c ?

Comment: `values` is pointer to `int`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - The answer by Bo in the one I linked is pretty good and succinct for a beginner. But I'll add the one you found in, sure.

Answer (score -2):

Here int values[]  is like pointers.

Comment: numbers that are divided into single characters?

Comment: Actually `int values[]` is adjusted to `int* values`, so it isn't an array.

Comment: got it.I've solved the problem,thx.

Comment: @MadhurGupta I like the confidence. :P