# Passing char arrays to functions that take char pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In C, why is it that I'm able to pass character arrays to functions that take a `char *` as an argument, but I cannot pass the address of an array to functions that take a `char **`?

**UPDATE:** Interestingly, changing the argument type to `char* qux[12]`  doesn't change the compiler warning at all

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(char* qux) { puts(qux); }
void bar(char** qux) { puts(*qux); }
void baz(char* qux[12]) { puts(*qux); }

int main() {
    char str[12] = "Hello there";

    foo(str);
    bar(&str); // Compiler warning
    baz(&str); // Same compiler warning

    return 0;
}
```

---

In the second case, I get a compiler warning:

```
warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char (*)[12]' to
         parameter of type 'char **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

What's going on here?

Comment: They're different types. Ask yourself: What is the size of `*qux`?

Comment: Try to understand basic difference between single and double pointers

Comment: I feel there should be a dupe for this question.

Comment: @ThiruShetty I understand the difference between single and double pointers, however I wasn't aware of array decay as mentioned in Someprogrammerdude's answer

Comment: I've tried quite a few search terms but please let me know if you find any @MFisherKDX !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573310/difference-between-passing-array-and-array-pointer-into-function-in-c

Comment: @AnttiHaapala My question is about `T*` and calling using `foo(bar)` vs `T**` and calling using `foo(&bar)` though, not really asking the difference between `T a[]` and `T *a`

Comment: If you replace `T` with `char *` it is pretty much your problem.

Comment: That link was for your update. `T *a` and `T a[]` in parameters are exactly equal so that for your "interesting find".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element. So in the call `foo(str)` it's really the same as `foo(&str[0])`. This is of type `char *` so it's all okay.

Now the second call, the one to `bar`, is a different matter. When you use `&str` you don't get a pointer to the arrays first element, you get a pointer to the *array itself*. And as the compiler noted, this is of type `char (*)[12]`, which is very different from (and incompatible with) `char **`.

Lastly, when you declare `baz` you say that the argument is of type `char *[12]`, that is you have an array or 12 *pointers* to char, not that you have a pointer to an array of 12 `char`. Furthermore, due to the array decay to pointer thing, `char *[12]` is actually *the same* as `char **`.

Comment: Oh I guess I didn't know about array decay, that's interesting. Is there a way to make that argument be a pointer to an array of 12 `char` instead of the other way around?

Comment: try this way.  `char *qux1 = NULL; qux1=qux; bar(&qux1);`

Comment: @BrunoEly I just told it to you, and it's also part of the error message: "... passing 'char (*)[12]' to...". Use e.g. `char (*qux)[12]` and you have a pointer to an array of 12 `char`. However, passing pointers to arrays like that is often not needed, passing a simple `char *` pointing to the first element is the common use-case.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude got it! Yeah that's how I usually do it, I just couldn't figure out what that error message meant and it's been bugging me for a while. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: "Furthermore, due to the array decay to pointer thing, char *[12] is actually the same as char **." An array is not the same as a pointer. An expression of array type is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element in many contexts, but not all.

Answer (score 2):

In C, `char *` represents a pointer to a contiguous sequence of characters. A contiguous sequence of characters with a null termination is what we call a string in C.

`char **` is a pointer to a contiguous sequence of strings, and since each string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by a null ('\0') character, `char **` represents a contiguous sequence to a contiguous sequence of null terminated characters.

Your declaration:

```
 char str[12] = "Hello there";
```

Declares `str` to be an array of characters of length 12, and it is initialized to the 12 characters `{'H','e','l','l','o',' ','t','h','e','r','e','\0'}`. This is compatible with the parameter in foo(), but not with `bar` and `baz` both of which expect a contiguous sequence of pointers to strings. That is why those two give you a compiler warning because the parameter is incompatible with the arguments passed in.