# Is there a difference in declaring an array with or without square braces in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, declaration, brackets

I'm still new to C++ and I've got a question concerning arrays as parameters in functions/ constructors. I've realized that it is possible to declare an array in two ways (maybe there are more, which I haven't seen before):
1.

```
    void foo(int arr[]);
```

2.

```
    void foo(int arr);
```

In both cases, arr can be used in the following way:

```
   arr[0] = 1;
```

But what is the difference between those? Or is it just a matter of clarity?

Comment: I've never heard of `[` and `]` being referred to as angular braces, people just call them "brackets" or "square brackets". Sometimes I hear `<` and `>` referred to as "angle brackets".

Comment: Those are *square brackets* not *angular braces*. :)

Comment: Perhaps you mean `(int *arr)` in your number 2?

Comment: `{}` - *braces*, `<>` - *angular brackets*, `[]`- *square brackets* `()` - *parentheses*.

Comment: @Galik `{}` are also sometimes called _curly brackets_

Comment: @Galik `{}` are often mentioned as curly brackets as well, but that's not the point of the question, is it?

Comment: You are right. I just mixed it up with the pointer to an array. Even though I knew that an array can be declared using a pointer, I thought there also was a way to declare an array like that.

Comment: @KyrSt That's why its a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Sure, but it kind of got messy here, wasn't trying to be rude

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748150/difference-between-int-array-and-int-array-in-a-function-parameter

Comment: In both cases, `arr` is a pointer.

Comment: @Aeropag - an array cannot be declared using a pointer, or vice versa.   They are different things entirely.   However, a pointer can be assigned to contain the address of the first element of an array, and array syntax can be used on that pointer to access elements of the array,   That is a SYNTACTIC equivalence (array syntax can be used to operate on a pointer, and pointer syntax can be used to operate on an array).   They are still VERY different things.

Comment: @Peter That's actually what I've meant, but I expressed it wrong. So, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is one is a variable, the other an array.

```
void my_func(int array[]); // Function with array parameter.
void your_func(int variable); // Function with variable parameter.
```

The notation:

```
int v;
v[5] = 6;
```

should generate a compilation error or warning because the `v` variable is not an array nor a pointer.