# Incrementing array variables inside and outside main function in C language

Tags: c, arrays

Earlier posts have described why array names cannot be incremented. But..
What about these two different ways of incrementing?

```
void f(int arr[]){
  printf("%d\n",*arr++);
  printf("%d\n",*arr);
}

int main(void){
  int arr[3]={1,2,3};
  f(arr);
  // COMPILE BY COMMENTING THESE TWO LINES BELOW AND ADDING THEM
  printf("%d\n",*arr++);
  printf("%d\n",*arr);
}
```

I am not able to figure why it works in one case and not in the other. Any suggestions/guidance welcome.

Comment: you can see this question/answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748150/difference-between-int-array-and-int-array-in-a-function-parameter

Comment: @Max that's different, has no bearing to the question here.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I think he has something to do with the question.

Comment: I understand the concept of compiler providing arrays as a syntactic sugar. What I was asking is as far as the feature of arrays is concerned this is not a consistent behaviour. Is it documented anywhere in the C language specification? If not then is it a bug? Should it be reported?

Answer (score 4):

Because `void f(int arr[])` is just syntactic sugar for `void f(int *arr)`.

Inside the `f` function, `arr` ist just a pointer and not an array.

Read [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) for more information.